# Tuning MySql my.cnf for Many Users

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm looking for some help tuning our my.cnf file to handle many current users (about 20 orders/minute). This particular site is in WordPress and running Woocommerce.

After a lot of reading online, I've come up with the settings below. The server is Debian 8 with 12 CPUs and 48GB RAM.

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 256K
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 80M

key_buffer      = 2G
max_allowed_packet  = 512M
thread_cache_size   = 256K
tmp_table_size      = 4G
max_heap_table_size = 4G
table_cache     = 1024
table_definition_cache  = 1024
myisam_recover          = FORCE,BACKUP
max_connections         = 300
wait_timeout        = 120
connect_timeout     = 120
interactive_timeout     = 120

innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 2G
innodb_io_capacity      = 1000
innodb_read_io_threads      = 32
innodb_thread_concurrency   = 0
innodb_write_io_threads     = 32
```

It seems to be running pretty good for now. Any additional thoughts? Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> query_cache_type = 1
> query_cache_limit = 256K
> query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
> query_cache_size = 80M
> ```

See https://dom.as/tech/query-cache-tuner/

> ```
> key_buffer      = 2G
> ```

Key buffer is only for MyISAM. You shouldn't use MyISAM.

> ```
> max_allowed_packet  = 512M
> thread_cache_size   = 256K
> tmp_table_size      = 4G
> max_heap_table_size = 4G
> ```

4G is probably way too high for the tmp table and heap table sizes. Keep in mind multiple threads can create temp tables concurrently.

> ```
> table_cache     = 1024
> table_definition_cache  = 1024
> ```

Probably overkill.

> ```
> myisam_recover          = FORCE,BACKUP
> ```

Also used only for MyISAM.

> ```
> max_connections         = 300
> ```

What does `show global status like 'max_used_connections'` say? Is it close to max_connections?

> ```
> wait_timeout        = 120
> connect_timeout     = 120
> interactive_timeout     = 120
>
> innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
> innodb_file_per_table          = 1
> innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 2G
> ```

Fine but with 48G of RAM, you can probably increase the buffer pool size.

Run `show engine innodb status` and look for these lines:

```
Buffer pool size        131072
Free buffers            0
Database pages          128000
```

Is your buffer pool always pegged full? If so, increase its size.

What's the total size of your database? You don't need the buffer pool to be *larger* than the total size of your data+indexes, but large enough to hold the frequently-accessed pages would be good.

```
select round(sum(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024, 2) as mb 
from information_schema.tables where engine='InnoDB'
```

> ```
> innodb_io_capacity      = 1000
> innodb_read_io_threads      = 32
> innodb_thread_concurrency   = 0
> innodb_write_io_threads     = 32
> ```

The io capacity might be greater than the ability of your disks to keep up. You didn't describe what your disk system is.

The io threads is way overkill for a Wordpress site with the traffic you describe. Run `show engine innodb status` and look for this line:

```
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
```

If you always see 0's on that line, you don't need more than the default 4 & 4 io threads.

Comment: Thank you. Point taken on query cache! Problem is that this is a fresh server without many historical stats. I need the database to be optimized for a large flash sale that could easily do over 1000 orders (sales) per hour. Handling that many users on cached pages is not a problem. My concern is through checkout and database interactions. Anything else you can recommend beyond what I've supplied for increased performance? Btw, the disks are SSD on this server is on Linode. Thanks again.

Comment: So 1000 orders per hour is one order every 3.6 seconds on average. Maybe one order uses a few hundred queries? So about 100 queries per second on average? I manage MySQL servers a little bit more powerful than yours, with 24 cores, 96G RAM, RAID (no SSD) disks. They frequently do 10,000 queries per second and they're okay.

Comment: Wow, 10K per sec sounds very fast! What does your cnf file look like? Do you keep the IO at 4/4? Anything that I missed in my cnf file that might help from yours? Are you using any type of object caching?

Comment: Yes, we leave the IO threads at the defaults. The biggest difference is that we have 64GB for the innodb buffer pool. The db servers have between about 400-600GB of data at any given time. We also increased the innodb_log_file_size=1G because we use large TEXT/BLOB columns. We use innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 for greatest durability, but we use caching RAID controllers, so it's still fast enough.

Comment: The application is responsible for caching data using Memcached. It also defers writes by using ActiveMQ. You're using Wordpress, so you probably aren't inclined to get into the code and change it.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Really appreciate your advice and input.

Comment: My pleasure. One more thing about the IO threads: They are handling *asynchronous* IO, so each thread is usually waiting on many IO requests. That's how they are able to handle high load without needing more threads.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. One more quick question: I have memcached installed as well. Will MySql take advantage of it by default?? I've allocated 2GB RAM to memcached. I want to be overly cautious with using W3TC or another WP caching plugin, especially with pages. Do you think enabling only object/database cache would have benefits..or could it cause issues without fully testing Woocommerce checkout?

Comment: MySQL does not know about and will not use Memcached directly. This is something your application would do. Typically your app would read data from the database, and copy it to Memcached. Subsequent requests for the data should look in Memcached first, and re-read it from MySQL only if it's not in cache. But this all happens with application code.